Missing packages for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS arm64
I have an ARM-based virtual machine running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-40-generic aarch64) at a small cloud provider. Today I was not able to install a new package; apt update and apt upgrade failed and gave errors about missing packages.
I tried several mirrors, but they are all missing some packages for Arm64. While manually checking a mirror from my browser, I noticed that all the other folders have a modification date of today.
Why are the Arm64 packages missing? Are they being built as I type this question? When will they be available?
The end of the output of sudo apt update:
Fetched 634 kB in 1s (455 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::103 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::103 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::103 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-backports/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::103 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Screenshot of http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-security/main/ without binary-arm64 folder:


Did you add the repo URIs manually? Shouldn't you be using ports.ubuntu.com (which does appear to include a noble-security component) for arm64?

@steeldriver Yes, I did. I have tried changing /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources to work with ports.ubuntu.com but I get the following errors:
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

If you use the ports repo you should use either http://ports.ubuntu.com or http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports, not http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

@muru Thank you for the tip, it worked! Do you have any idea what might have happened with arm64 packages on other mirrors? This machine was working perfectly for months with the previous mirror.

Many mirrors just mirror the main repos at archive.ubuntu.com, a lot of them don't look at ports at all. Which mirror were you using before?

I was using my cloud provider's private mirror; I guess they changed something in their config. I have just realised that arm64 packages are not on archive.ubuntu.com. Thank you once again!
